# Get a filtered Query Output for Orders bought along with certain items excluding certain items bought along with them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need a help to get the order that were bought along with apple Item excluding those order that were bought along with certain items too. for example: if a customer bought an Apple within his order and along with that he also bought salad, i need to exclude that order no from my query output since my exclusion item is Salad and my base item is Apple.

```
    OrderID          ItemCode          ItemName          Price
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1000001          100               Apple               5
    1000001          101               Salad               15 
    1000001          102               Coffee              5.5 
    1000002          110               Bread               2.5 
    1000002          120               Banana              7.5 
    1000003          105               Apple               115 
    1000003          108               Fish                75 
    1000004          115               Cake                3.5 
    1000004          102               Apple               5.5 
    1000004          144               CupCake             10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution(not the best) is using `Exists` and `Not Exists` -

```
select *
from @xyz as T1
where
exists (select 1 from @xyz as T2 where T2.OrderID = T1.OrderID and T2.ItemName = 'Apple')
and
not exists (select 1 from @xyz as T3 where T3.OrderID = T1.OrderID and T3.ItemName = 'Salad')
```

Another solution using `Group By` -

```
select OrderID
from @xyz as T1
group by OrderId
having sum(case ItemName when 'Apple' then 1 when 'Salad' then -1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Input data-

```
declare @xyz table (OrderID int,ItemCode int,ItemName varchar(100),Price real)
insert into @xyz
select     1000001,  100,   'Apple'               ,5   union all
select     1000001,  101,   'Salad'               ,15  union all
select     1000001,  102,   'Coffee'              ,5.5 union all
select     1000002,  110,   'Bread'               ,2.5 union all
select     1000002,  120,   'Banana'              ,7.5 union all
select     1000003,  105,   'Apple'               ,115 union all
select     1000003,  108,   'Fish'                ,75  union all
select     1000004,  115,   'Cake'                ,3.5 union all
select     1000004,  102,   'Apple'               ,5.5 union all
select     1000004,  144,   'CupCake'             ,10
```